# Change bootstrap date format using angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

Using ng bootstrap datepicker, I am getting standard date format as `2018-08-13T23:19:43.000Z`. I need to change format to `DD/MM/YYYY ({16/08/2018 12:00:00 AM})` using Angular 2.

I need the change for the input field.

Source Code:

```
 <input type="text" datetime="yyyy-MM-dd" class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp1" [ngModel]=" filter.activityFrom | amDateFormat:'DD/MM/YYYY'"
(ngModelChange)="filter.activityFrom = $event" ngbDatepicker #d1="ngbDatepicker">
<button class="input-group-addon" (click)="d1.toggle()" type="button">
 <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
```

Comment: Where is the source code?

Comment: If you are getting Date in `amDateFormat`  then it's very easy just use `Date Pipe`

Comment: Do you want to change the format within `ngModel` variable `filter.activityFrom` or just format it for display?

Comment: I want to change it in the ngModel variable

Answer (score 0):

.ts file

```
dateNow : Date = new Date();
dateNowISO = this.dateNow.toISOString();
```

.html file

`{{dateNowISO | date: dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss}}`